# Style a single row in a Telerik MVC Grid - Client Side

Tags: jquery, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am trying to style only one row (from the client) of a Grid.

Here is my setup:
I am using Ajax binding to load the initial Grid data.  After that, I am editing all data from the Client side based on events from other controls.  So, a user may click some other control which causes a row to be "highlighted" on my Gird (without ever actually touching the grid).

I did some inspecting (with firebug) and see that the  in the table that gets created does not have an ID or a class (except the alternating rows) so I don't see a way to access that  element.  I would like to use jQuery and call the .addClass() and .removeClass() methods on the rows, but I don't quite know how to access them.  At this point I will take any solution ... so, is this something that is possible?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use the client-side row template and re-bind the grid when these external actions occur.  Here's Telerik's example of the client-side row template to be used when doing ajax binding:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid<Customer>()
   .Name("Grid")
   .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("Action", "Controller"))
   .Columns(columns =>
   {
       columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerID);
       columns.Bound(c => c.ContactName);
       columns.Bound(c => c.Country);
   })
   .ClientRowTemplate(grid => "<ul>" +
           "<li>CustomerID: <#= CustomerID #></li>" +
           "<li>Contact Name: <#= ContactName #></li>" +
           "<li>Country: <#= Country #></li>" +
        "</ul>" 
   )
%>
```

This might allow you to inject information into each row you can use to highlight.

More documentation about it on [Telerik's site](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-row-template.html).

Comment: Thanks, that is not what I did, but it would work AND it led me down the right path.  I ended up adding a hidden column with a .ClientTemplate("<div id='ciq-hg-row-<#= GroupNumber#>'></div>"), so that I could find the <div> buy the ID, then looking at the .parent().parent() (<td>.<tr>) to get the row.  I then styled the row.  I posted that code in this  thread.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the .ClientTemplate() to add a  to a hidden  element, then found the row it belongs to by finding the row's parent().parent().

Grid Razor:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<Multimedia.Web.Models.GroupModel>()
    .Name("group-grid")
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_GroupGridAjaxBinding", "TelerikControls"))

    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.GroupNumber).Width("30%");
        columns.Bound(o => o.GroupName).Width("80%").Title("Name");
        columns.Bound(o => o.GroupNumber).Hidden(true).ClientTemplate("<div id='group-row-<#= GroupNumber#>'></div>"); //i will find this <td> by the <div> id
    })

   .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled(true))
   .Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled(true))
   .Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled(false))
   .Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled(false))
   .Groupable(grouping => grouping.Enabled(false))
   .Footer(false)
)
```

And then, in my JavaScript, I was able to access the table row using the following jQuery:

```
var groupNum = getGroupNumSomehow();
$('#group-row-' + groupNum).parent().parent().addClass('highlight');
```

And it worked!